# Export data with formula between spss V22 and excel on windows 8 32 bit laptop

Tags: excel-formula, spss

Is there a method to exchange (import/export) data with their formulas between excel and SPSS?

Some times after preparing your file in excel and importing it into SPSS you would like to add new variable with calculation (whether variable dependent or independent). However, in many occasions you would do so for many variables.

Your ultimate wish is not to have to rewrite the calculation in the other file type (the copy or the original).

So after I calculate the new variables in SPSS, is it possible to just export these variables with their formulas?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it is not possible. I neither see any benefit in having such capability.

Why not just use Excel/VBA automation instead of SPSS if your ultimate goal is to have Excel spreadsheets as final deliverable?

Only thing as close would be to store the formula as strings and then convert to as formulas in Excel in some way. But that would be ridiculously complicated referencing row and column numbers and letter to construct the formula string.

Answer (score 0):

As Jignesh said, there is no direct way to do this, but it is certainly possible to use the Excel VBA libraries from Statistics to direct computation in Excel.  The risk, though, is that you are likely to have some transformations done on the Excel side and some on the SPSS side, and keeping these straight would be difficult and fraught with the risk of error.  It would be best to ensure that all the transformations happen on one side or the other and use the import/export capabilities of Statistics to synchronize this.